# How to ensure all data going in and out of a database is utf-8 encoded?

Tags: php, mysql, json, bash, shell

I just learned about character sets today, so forgive the newb factor if this is confusing.  Please ask for clarification if it's needed.

I wrote a program in php which recursively goes through the files in a folder and stores the file names in a database.  The file names are then all exported from the database in json format using the `json_encode($array)` function.

However this function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.  And since a few of the key-value pairs in the json export have the value of `null`, I'm lead to believe that those strings of filenames taken from the database are in fact not utf-8.

I've ensured that all the data going in and out of the the database is utf-8 by setting the defaults to utf-8 in `my.cnf` and restarting mysql from the command line using `service mysql restart`

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8
```

I then created my database, the table and all the columns in the table and confirmed that the database, table and all the columns are in fact utf-8

**Checks if database is utf-8**

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";
```

**Checks if table is utf-8**

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND T.table_name = "tablename";
```

**Checks if field is utf-8**

```
SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
WHERE table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND table_name = "tablename"
  AND column_name = "columnname";
```

There's this file that has the characters –µ–ª–∫—É–Ω—á–∏–∫ in the file name.  When it's stored in the database the values appear as â€“Â©â€“Âµâ€“Âªâ€“â'.

Per my database settings, are all the strings going in and out of my database utf-8?

What can I do to ensure the data I am SELECT'ing from the database is utf-8, so I can perform `json_encode($array)`? (NOTE: this function only works on utf-8 encoded data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know how you can ensure everything coming out is UTF-8 (now I'm curious too!), but a starting point would be trying this in your PHP:

```
$encodedNames = array();
$errors = array();

// Loop through all of the filenames
foreach($filenames as $filename)
{
  // Check if it's UTF-8 encoded
  if('UTF-8' === mb_detect_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8', true))
  {
    $encodedNames[] = $filename;
  }
  else
  {
    $errors[] = $filename;
  }
}

// json_encode the UTF-8 filenames
$jsonString = json_encode($encodedNames);

// Log the other filenames here so you can deal with them later...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Thanks Steve, will try this out soon.  As far as character encodings are concerned, doesn't the proper database setup ensure that the strings stored in the database are utf-8?  Is it just when they're stored in a php array that they become non-utf8?

Comment: I'm not really sure; I would think that you're right in that a proper database setup ensures proper encoding (I'm not really a DB guy), but I also just saw `mysql_set_charset` - maybe it has something to do with that? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: Hey Steve, here's something interesting I just learned - MySQL PDO ignores the charset specification in it's dsn, so you have to manualy set the name to utf-8 upon connecting.